# How to download microdnf in maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have the following Docker file. When I run for 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8' I get '/bin/sh: 1: microdnf: not found' but I get no such message when 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15' runs. Does anyone know how to download microdnf when using 'maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8'? Docker file follows:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15
#FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8

ARG CHROME_VERSION=87.0.4280.88-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=87.0.4280.88
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''
EXPOSE 4444

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I ma seeing the output:

```
Step 4/13 : RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
 ---> Running in d37ab0aa1655
/bin/sh: 1: microdnf: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome' returned a non-zero code: 127
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Comment: You can use `jar` to unzip a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to the fact that jdk 15 version is based on the Oracle Linux, which supports microdnf. openjdk8 version does not support that.

You can take a look on that right there:

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/openjdk-8/Dockerfile

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/openjdk-15/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

openjdk:8 image is based on Debian buster

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/3878ca2dbb39c8f65337887f38a9b8376b8116ff/library/openjdk#L227-L231

openjdk:15 image is based on Oracle Linux 8

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/3878ca2dbb39c8f65337887f38a9b8376b8116ff/library/openjdk#L101-L105

Maven images inherit those

https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/openjdk-8/Dockerfile#L1
https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/master/openjdk-15/Dockerfile#L1